# Remove quotes when passing a column name via parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I am trying to do the following:

```
 SELECT @IDENTITY_COLUMN = (
  SELECT COLUMN_NAME
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tbltest1'


SELECT @LAST_VALUE_USED = (
SELECT ISNULL(MAX(@IDENTITY_COLUMN),0)
FROM tbltest1
)
```

If there are no rows, it works fine but when there is a row, the second query is returning a string that has the column name and I believe it is because `@IDENTITY_COLUMN`has quotes in it. Hence I am getting `Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'columnname' to data type int`. How can I solve this problem?

Help appreciated!

Comment: What's `@IDENTITY_COLUMN` type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're trying to get the maximum value of an `IDENTITY` column from a table if such a column exists. You'd need dynamic SQL for that. Something like:

```
DECLARE @identity_column sysname;
DECLARE @query nvarchar(MAX);

SET @identity_column = (SELECT column_name
                               FROM information_schema.columns
                                    WHERE table_name = 'tbltest1');
IF @identity_column IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
  SET @query = '
SELECT isnull(max(' + quotename(@identity_column) + '), 0)
       FROM tbltest1;
';
  EXECUTE (@query);
END;
```

Note:

- For object names use `sysname`, that's an extra type for them. Don't use `varchar` or `navarchar` etc..
- Always use `quotename()` if embedding object names in a dynamic query. That'll prevent funny things from happen, if the object name contains non alpha numeric characters or is odd in other ways.